# Group by date (or month or ...) instead of "A long time ago" in explorer on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

There seems to be no recent, current and clear answer to the simple question:

How can I FIX* the group by feature in the explorer in windows 10 so that it is actually grouped by time units in usable form?

Current result:

- Yesterday
- Earlier this week
- A long time ago

Targeted result:

- 2018 August
- 2018 July
- ...

Or:

- 2018.05.07
- 2018.05.06
- ...

*I'm having a hard time believing that there is no obvious option, first and foremost because it is absolutely useless for doing actual work.

And just in case:

Did you google it? Yes:

- "Not possible" related to older Windows versions
- "Use the arrange by ... " related to the pictures library